# Convert DateTimeString to Ticks in DbMigration Entity Framework Compact CE

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, database-migration

I need to change timestamp column in my compact ce 4.0  which currently is a `string` and formated:
"06.01.2016 22.18.47.977". To a column of type `Long` which holds DateTime.Ticks instead.

The DbMigration scripts proposal is obviously not what i want:

```
AlterColumn("dbo.LogRecords", "Timestamp",c => c.Long(nullable: false));
```

My initial thought was to use DATEDIFF to calculate number of millisecond*10.

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate ) *10=ticks
```

Unfortunatly it seems as if this function can only return `int` which fails with overflow. 
Is there a way to do these kind of migrations in the migration script?

Ideally something like:

```
AlterColumn("dbo.LogRecords", "Timestamp",c => c.Long(nullable: false,
(p =>DateTime.ParseExact(p.Timestamp, "MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", culture).Ticks));
```

Comment: You can never change a column and re-calculate/re-insert its values in one DDL statement. I think you should add a new column and populate in in the `Seed` method. Remove the old column in a later migration.

Comment: Ok, I will look into using Seed method. Can seed method run in migration on startup? I cant access users databases manully. It have to be automated on startup.